# nlnum problem of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm having a difficulty to NDSolve a ODE due to nlnum (according to the error message). Below is the code I have. First of all are functions:

```
energy = Subdivide[0, 50, 2]; theta = Subdivide[0, 1, 2]; ni = Length[theta]; nj = Length[energy];
For[j = 2, j <= nj, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i <= ni, i++, 
   P[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t] = {Px[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Py[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t], Pz[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t]}]];
For[j = 2, j <= nj, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i <= ni, i++, 
   Pbar[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], 
     t] = {Pbarx[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Pbary[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Pbarz[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t]}]];
B={0.02,0,0.9998};
MPP = Flatten[
   Table[D[P[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t], t] == 
     Cross[1/energy[[j]] B, 
       P[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t]] +
      Cross[Sum[(1 - theta[[ii]] theta[[i]]) (theta[[ii]] - 
           theta[[ii - 1]])
         Sum[(energy[[jj]] P[theta[[ii]], energy[[jj]], t] - 
             energy[[jj]] Pbar[theta[[ii]], energy[[jj]], 
               t]) (energy[[jj]] - energy[[jj - 1]]), {jj, 2, 
           nj}], {ii, 1, ni}], P[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t]], {i, 1, 
     ni}, {j, 2, nj}]];
MPV = Flatten[
   Table[P[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t] == {0, 0, 1} /. t -> 10, {i, 1,
      ni}, {j, 2, nj}]];
MPbarP = Flatten[
   Table[D[Pbar[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t], t] == 
     Cross[-1/energy[[j]] B, 
       Pbar[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t]] +
      Cross[Sum[(1 - theta[[ii]] theta[[i]]) (theta[[ii]] - 
           theta[[ii - 1]])
         Sum[(energy[[jj]] P[theta[[ii]], energy[[jj]], t] - 
             energy[[jj]] Pbar[theta[[ii]], energy[[jj]], 
               t]) (energy[[jj]] - energy[[jj - 1]]), {jj, 2, 
           nj}], {ii, 1, ni}], Pbar[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t]], {i, 
     1, ni}, {j, 2, nj}]];
MPbarV = Flatten[
   Table[Pbar[theta[[i]], energy[[j]], t] == {0, 0, 1} /. t -> 10, {i,
      1, ni}, {j, 2, nj}]];
Ms = Join[MPP, MPbarP, MPV, MPbarV];
Msss = NDSolve[Ms, Pz[theta[[2]], energy[[2]], t], {t, 10, 50}, 
  MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
```

My code is very long and hard to read, sorry about that.

You can find that `P` and `Pbar` are vectors. I don't know is there any way better to define them. If you know please tell me.

If you have any ways to make my code easy to read(write in another way), thanks to tell me.

The ODE question I want to solve have two integrates and I have no idea how to do it and make it simple(in my thoughts), so I use two sum.

In other to make the error more clearly and the code easier to read, the code missed many coefficients, so the equation may cant't be solved numerically.

The follow one is original equation with initial value of it, the value of coefficients are included also. I have no idea how to solve it by `NDSolve`. If anyone have ideas how to do this?

Coefficients:

```
B = {0.02, 0, 0.9998};z = {0, 0, 1};zeta = 1.202;Ebare = 10;Ebaree = 15;Ebarx = 24;betae = 0.315;betaee = 0.21;betax = 0.131;u =2.13386*10^6;w = 1/0.197;\[Lambda] =(1.92893*10^11 E^(-7.24384 ArcSin[1 - 0.0000183824 t]^1.1))/t^2.4;
```

Equations:

```
D[P[theta, energy, t], 
   t] == {w/energy B + \[Lambda] z + 
     u 2/(3 zeta)
       Integrate[(1 - 
          theta theta1) Integrate[(((
              betae (betae energy1)^2)/((E^(betae energy1) + 
                 1) Ebare) + (
              betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax energy1) + 
                 1) Ebarx)) P[theta1, energy1, 
             t] - ((betaee (betaee energy1)^2)/((E^(betaee energy1) + 
                 1) Ebaree) + (
              betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax energy1) + 
                 1) Ebarx)) Pbar[theta1, energy1, t]), {energy1, 0, 
          50}], {theta1, Cos[ArcSin[10/t]], 1}]}\[Cross]P[theta, 
    energy, t];
D[Pbar[theta, energy, t], 
   t] == {-w/energy B + \[Lambda] z + 
     u 2/(3 zeta)
       Integrate[(1 - 
          theta theta1) Integrate[(((
              betae (betae energy1)^2)/((E^(betae energy1) + 
                 1) Ebare) + (
              betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax energy1) + 
                 1) Ebarx)) P[theta1, energy1, 
             t] - ((betaee (betaee energy1)^2)/((E^(betaee energy1) + 
                 1) Ebaree) + (
              betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax energy1) + 
                 1) Ebarx)) Pbar[theta1, energy1, t]), {energy1, 0, 
          50}], {theta1, Cos[ArcSin[10/t]], 1}]}\[Cross]Pbar[theta, 
    energy, t];
```

Initial value:

```
P[theta, energy, 10] == {0, 
   0, ((betae (betae energy)^2)/((E^(betae energy) + 1) Ebare) - (
    betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 1) Ebarx))/((
    betae (betae energy)^2)/((E^(betae energy) + 1) Ebare) + (
    betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 1) Ebarx))};
Pbar[theta, energy, 10] == {0, 
  0, ((betaee (betaee energy)^2)/((E^(betaee energy) + 1) Ebaree) - (
   betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 1) Ebarx))/((
   betaee (betaee energy)^2)/((E^(betaee energy) + 1) Ebaree) + (
   betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 1) Ebarx))}
```

Comment: Definition of `B` is missing.

Comment: Why do functions have 3 arguments, but in the NDSolve only t? What do the original equations look like?

Comment: @xzczd definition of `B={0.02,0,0.9998}` has been added. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexTrounev the `energy` term and `theta` term has been integrate in original equation, in my function it has been summed, so the dimension of final equation is equal to dimension of energy times dimension of theta times 2 times 3: `ni*nj*2*3`

Comment: I recognize that the equation is wrong :( , the sum of theta has a term `theta[0]` which is out of define. So the problem has been solved, but I want to improve my codes and make it more easy to read. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the code corrected?

Comment: @AlexTrounev after change the sum of `theta` from `{ii,1,ni}` to `{ii,2,ni}` it turns to be right. I have no idea whether I need to change it.

Comment: I have such a message `Cross::nonn1: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev "xzczd" has pointed out that `B` is not defined in my original code, and I have added it.

Comment: I check the current code after all the fixes. Got a message `Cross::nonn1: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev I fill very sorry for the trouble I bring to those who read my question and my code with great patient like you. I change the my code again and then it shows the error `nlnum` because of the term `theta[0]` in sum is out of define.

Comment: I fixed two errors, the code works. And what is expected to receive?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Is there anyway to simplify my codes, like other ways to define `P`, `Pbar` or write a class of equation not by `Table`. The original equation is an ODE equation with integrate of `energy` and `theta` of `P[theta, energy, t]`, `Pbar[theta, energy, t]`. Can MMA solve this directly  instead of write `energy` and `theta` in discrete form?

Comment: Your code can be rewritten using parametric functions. Just formulate the original model. Although I got a numerical result with this code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I will added original equation in my question and ask if anyone knows how to solve it.

Comment: This problem can be solved by the method of successive approximations. We'll have to work hard on the code.

Comment: We already have a number of posts about [vectorization of differential equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdifferential-equations%5D+vectorization), have you checked them? BTW, you'd better put a bit more effort in improving your question, or even consider deleting this and starting a new question (it should be asked in a better way, of course), given your target is largely changed now. As to how to improve the question, for example, you may consider adding some background information, and the $\LaTeX$ form of the equation system to the post.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the second question, since the first one already has a solution. We will use the method of successive approximations. My message shows only the first step. I discovered numerical instability, so I will continue after consulting with the author of the model.As a zero approximation, we use the initial data. When integrating on `theta1` variable interval  `{theta1, Cos[ArcSin[10/t]], 1}` is mapped to `{x,0,1}`.

```
B = {0.02, 0, 0.9998}; t0 = 10; tm = 50; z = {0, 0, 
  1}; zeta = 1.202; Ebare = 10; Ebaree = 15; Ebarx = 24; betae = \
0.315; betaee = 0.21; betax = 0.131; u = 2.13386*10^6; w = 
 1/0.197; \[Lambda][
  t_] := (1.92893*10^11 E^(-7.24384 ArcSin[1 - 0.0000183824 t]^1.1))/
  t^2.4; q[t_] := Cos[ArcSin[10/t]]; theta1 = q[t] + (1 - q[t])*x; dth = 
 1 - q[t];

P0 = {0, 0, ((betae (betae energy)^2)/((E^(betae energy) + 
           1) Ebare) - (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 
           1) Ebarx))/((betae (betae energy)^2)/((E^(betae energy) + 
           1) Ebare) + (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 
           1) Ebarx))};
Pbar0 = {0, 
   0, ((betaee (betaee energy)^2)/((E^(betaee energy) + 
           1) Ebaree) - (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 
           1) Ebarx))/((betaee (betaee energy)^2)/((E^(betaee energy) \
+ 1) Ebaree) + (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 
           1) Ebarx))};
(*Go back to the label*)
I1 = ((((betae (betae energy1)^2)/((E^(betae energy1) + 
             1) Ebare) + (betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax \
energy1) + 
             1) Ebarx)) P0 - ((betaee (betaee energy1)^2)/((E^(betaee \
energy1) + 
             1) Ebaree) + (betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax \
energy1) + 1) Ebarx)) Pbar0));
    Table[f11[i] = 
   Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{{t, energy}, 
       NIntegrate[I1[[i]]*dth, {energy1, 1, 51}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 5]}, {t, t0, tm, 2}, {energy, 1, 51, 5}], 
     1]], {i, 1, 3}];
Table[f12[i] = 
   Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{{t, energy}, 
       NIntegrate[theta1*I1[[i]]*dth, {energy1, 1, 51}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 5]}, {t, t0, tm, 2}, {energy, 1, 51, 5}], 
     1]], {i, 1, 3}];
F1 = Table[
   u 2/(3 zeta)*(f11[i][t, energy] - theta *f12[i][t, energy]), {i, 1,
     3}];
I2 = ((((betae (betae energy1)^2)/((E^(betae energy1) + 
             1) Ebare) + (betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax \
energy1) + 
             1) Ebarx)) P0 - ((betaee (betaee energy1)^2)/((E^(betaee \
energy1) + 
             1) Ebaree) + (betax (betax energy1)^2)/((E^(betax \
energy1) + 1) Ebarx)) Pbar0));
Table[f21[i] = 
   Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{{t, energy}, 
       NIntegrate[I2[[i]]*dth, {energy1, 1, 51}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 5]}, {t, t0, tm, 2}, {energy, 1, 51, 5}], 
     1]], {i, 1, 3}];
Table[f22[i] = 
   Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{{t, energy}, 
       NIntegrate[theta1*I2[[i]]*dth, {energy1, 1, 51}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 5]}, {t, t0, tm, 2}, {energy, 1, 51, 5}], 
     1]], {i, 1, 3}];
F2 = Table[
   u 2/(3 zeta)*(f21[i][t, energy] - theta *f22[i][t, energy]), {i, 1,
     3}];
P = {P1[t], P2[t], P3[t]}; Pbar = {PB1[t], PB2[t], PB3[t]};
eq1 = D[P, t] - Cross[w/energy B + \[Lambda][t] z + F1, P]; eq2 = 
 D[Pbar, t] - Cross[-w/energy B + \[Lambda][t] z + F2, Pbar];
ic = {P1[t0] == 0, P2[t0] == 0, 
   P3[t0] == ((betae (betae energy)^2)/((E^(betae energy) + 
            1) Ebare) - (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 
            1) Ebarx))/((betae (betae energy)^2)/((E^(betae energy) + 
            1) Ebare) + (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) + 
            1) Ebarx)),
   PB1[t0] == 0, PB2[t0] == 0, 
   PB3[t0] == ((betaee (betaee energy)^2)/((E^(betaee energy) + 
            1) Ebaree) - (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) \
+ 1) Ebarx))/((betaee (betaee energy)^2)/((E^(betaee energy) + 
            1) Ebaree) + (betax (betax energy)^2)/((E^(betax energy) \
+ 1) Ebarx))};


P10 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Table[{eq1[[j]] == 0, 
      eq2[[j]] == 0}, {j, 1, 3}], ic}, 
   P1, {t, t0, tm}, {theta, energy}];



 {Plot[Evaluate[Table[P10[.5, energy][t], {energy, 10, 50, 10}]], {t, 
   t0, tm}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[P10[.5, energy][t], {energy, 5, 10, 1}]], {t, t0,
    tm}], Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[P10[.5, energy][t], {energy, 1, 4, 1}]], {t, t0, 
   tm}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Divergence occurs at the lower limit `energy = 1`. The author assumed the lower limit `energy = 0`, but in this case the integrals are not calculated due to the error `1/0`. Therefore, I moved the lower limit to `energy = 1`, but apparently it will be necessary to increase even more. And so, we got the solution in the first step in the form of functions `P0={P10[theta, energy][t],P20[theta, energy][t],P30[theta, energy][t]}, Pbar0={PB10[theta, energy][t],PB20[theta, energy][t],PB30[theta, energy][t]}`. We return to the label `(*Go back to the label*)` and repeat.

Comment: I fell very sorry for connect you too late.
I have some questions:
1. you mentioned that there is an error `1/0`, I think this can be solve by use `\$MachineEpsilon` as the low limit as MMA suggested.
2.I doubt that the use of `Interpolation` and `NIntegrate` is reasonable. In my question, the integrate term "P(theta, energy, t)" is changed, but you use initial condition to "Interpolation" one, I draw the `Interpolation` of `f11` and find that `P` changed to "0" very quickly so that the third term `F1` is almost equal to "0" which is certainly not what I want.

Comment: All in our hands. We can use any initial approximation. I just showed the method. And you can find a solution yourself.