# Is there any way to save time using of "Cross" or "Table"?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, list-manipulation, parallelization

I need to solve a equation by `NDSlove`, so I write the equation first, but it takes me a lot of time.
The follow is my code

```
energy = Subdivide[0, 50, 5];
theta0 = Reverse[N[ArcSin[Subdivide[0, 1, 5]]]]
theta = Cos[
   ArcSin[(R Sin[theta0])/Sqrt[
    t^2 + 2 R t Cos[theta0] + R^2 Cos[theta0]^2 + R^2 Sin[theta0]^2]]];
ni = Length[theta];nj = Length[energy];
Ebare = 10;Ebaree = 15;Ebarx = 24;betae = 0.315;betaee = 0.21;betax = 0.131;R = 10;
Fj = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, (
    betae (betae x)^2)/((E^(betae x) + 1) Ebare) + (
    betax (betax x)^2)/((E^(betax x) + 1) Ebarx)];
Fjbar = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, ((
     betaee (betaee x)^2)/((E^(betaee x) + 1) Ebaree) + (
     betax (betax x)^2)/((E^(betax x) + 1) Ebarx)) ];
For[j = 2, j <= nj, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i <= ni, i++, 
   P[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t] = {Px[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Py[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Pz[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t]}]];
For[j = 2, j <= nj, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i <= ni, i++, 
   Pbar[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], 
     t] = {Pbarx[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Pbary[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
     Pbarz[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t]}]];
Clear["i", "j"];
timing = AbsoluteTiming[
   MPP = Flatten[
     ParallelTable[D[P[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t], t] == 
       Cross[Sum[(1 - theta[[ii]] theta[[i]]) (theta[[ii]] - 
            theta[[ii - 
               1]]) Sum[(Fj[energy[[jj]]] P[theta0[[ii]], 
                energy[[jj]], t] - 
              Fjbar[energy[[jj]]] Pbar[theta0[[ii]], energy[[jj]], 
                t]) (energy[[jj]] - energy[[jj - 1]]), {jj, 2, 
            nj}], {ii, 2, ni}], P[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t]], {i, 
       1, ni}, {j, 2, nj}]]];
timing[[1]]
```

I run the former code in a HPC which have 16 kernels, when `ni=nj=6`, the output is `301...`, when `ni=6, nj=8` the output is `1229...s`, as you can find the time used arise quiet quickly. And what final I want is `ni=80, nj=32`, I can't accept the time used of this.

So, is there anyway to save time to do `Table` or `Cross`. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Honestly, this is not the way to write down a system of differential equations of this size. You try to press everything into symbolic computations. But these are slow. Better submit the system to `NDSolve` in the form `D[X[t], t] == F[X[t]]` with a function `F[x_?NumericQ]:=` that eats a _numeric_ vector and throws out the forcing term. Then you can make use of fast operations like `Dot` for matrices and vectors.

Comment: Otherwise it does actually not matter if you work on an "HPC" or not; you have to reformulate your problem in a way such that an HPC can play out it strengths -- and that is mere number crunching power.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm not really understand what you mean, do you mean that I should not do `D[P[t], t]` but do `D[Px[t]]`, `D[Py[t]]`, `D[Pz[t]]` separately?

Comment: I would go more into detail if I were able to understand what the right hand sides of the equations is supposed to do. For instance, I am puzzled what `Cross` is supposed to do there. Are the `P` supposed to be vector-valued? In total, there is really not enough information for providing a detailed answer. Certainly, your system _is_ very expensive as each degree of freedom seems to couple nontrivially with all the other ones.

Comment: If possible, describe your problem in natural language.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Really sorry about that, I miss the definition of `P` and `Pbar`. Now you could just copy my code and it can run to get the time used. I follow your advice do `D[P[t]]` separately, it almost finished right away, I'm checking my code of the separately definition, and try to make it more clearly. As you can see if it write separately, it will be too long.

Comment: Marginally related: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica) and [Avoiding procedural loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396)

Comment: How is this related to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185067/nlnum-problem-of-ndsolve?noredirect=1#comment482667_185067 ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's not entirely unrelated, the `Cross` in that question won't take such a long time. In other words, I didn't meet this problem in that question. But both question are proposed to solve the same physics problem. I ask this new question is because I did't find any related question mentioned the time used by `Cross` in this forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a 51 x 31 computation taking around a minute without parallelization. All I really did was precompute the cross product and substitute the components.  Perhaps `Cross[]` does some symbolic operations that are avoided this way.  The 6 x 6 calculation took around `0.03` seconds.

```
energy = Subdivide[0., 50., 50];
theta0 = Reverse[N[ArcSin[Subdivide[0., 1., 30]]]];
(* ... *)

timing = AbsoluteTiming[
   MPP = Flatten[
     Table[D[P[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t], 
        t] == (Cross[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}] /. 
         Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f} -> 
           Join[Sum[(1 - theta[[ii]] theta[[i]]) (theta[[ii]] - 
                theta[[ii - 
                   1]]) Sum[(Fj[energy[[jj]]] P[theta0[[ii]], 
                    energy[[jj]], t] - 
                  Fjbar[energy[[jj]]] Pbar[theta0[[ii]], energy[[jj]],
                     t]) (energy[[jj]] - energy[[jj - 1]]), {jj, 2, 
                nj}], {ii, 2, ni}], 
            P[theta0[[i]], energy[[j]], t]]]), {i, 1, ni}, {j, 2, 
       nj}]]];
timing[[1]]

(*  67.5372  *)
```

`Compile` isn't always faster, especially when the code depends heavily on external variables.  The following changes reduces the computation to `42.3379` seconds:

```
Fj = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, (betae (betae x)^2)/((E^(betae x) + 
          1) Ebare) + (betax (betax x)^2)/((E^(betax x) + 1) Ebarx) //
     Evaluate];
Fjbar = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, ((betaee (betaee x)^2)/((E^(betaee x) + 
           1) Ebaree) + (betax (betax x)^2)/((E^(betax x) + 
           1) Ebarx)) // Evaluate];
```

If you don't compile the expressions at all, it takes `45.0974` sec., which shows how little `Compile` helps in this application.